# Printing out from a file

Tags: server, apache2, iptables

I have a file which contains the following details after doing an `nmap` scan:

```
Host: 45.310.302.11 (li982-11.members.ionic.com)    
Ports: 21/closed/tcp//ftp///, 22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 5.3 (protocol 2.0)/, 23/closed/tcp//telnet///, 25/closed/tcp//smtp///, 53/closed/tcp//domain///, 80/open/tcp//http//Apache httpd/, 110/closed/tcp//pop3///, 111/closed/tcp//rpcbind///, 135/filtered/tcp//msrpc///, 139/filtered/tcp//netbios-ssn///, 143/closed/tcp//imap///, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//Apache httpd/, 445/filtered/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 993/closed/tcp//imaps///, 995/closed/tcp//pop3s///, 1723/closed/tcp//pptp///, 3306/open/tcp//mysql//MySQL 5.7.24/, 3389/closed/tcp//ms-wbt-server///, 5900/closed/tcp//vnc///, 8080/closed/tcp//http-proxy///
```

I want to print out only the lines that contain has port 80 and 443 open.
This is the below code i used. It can print out port 80 but not 443

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}.* 80/open/tcp//http//.*" ~/Downloads/nmap-output.txt|cut -d, -f1,6 --output-delimiter=" "|cut -d ' ' -f1,2,5
```

How can I print out port 443?

Comment: which `nmap` option did you use? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1184398/edit) your answer by adding the command

Comment: `nmap` has an option to produce output in machine-readable format. You should simply use that instead of try to whip up your own ad-hoc parser with tools which are not really up for the job.

Comment: The nmap scan has already been done before i resume work so i dont know the nmap option used. My task is to filter through the file and print only the IPs  that have port 80 and 443 open.

I can print all IPs with port 80 open but not 443.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way but this is what I would do. First convert the input file:

```
$ cat nmap-scan.txt

Host: 45.310.302.11 (li982-11.members.ionic.com)    
Ports: 21/closed/tcp//ftp///, 22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 5.3 (protocol 2.0)/, 23/closed/tcp//telnet///, 25/closed/tcp//smtp///, 53/closed/tcp//domain///, 80/open/tcp//http//Apache httpd/, 110/closed/tcp//pop3///, 111/closed/tcp//rpcbind///, 135/filtered/tcp//msrpc///, 139/filtered/tcp//netbios-ssn///, 143/closed/tcp//imap///, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//Apache httpd/, 445/filtered/tcp//microsoft-ds///, 993/closed/tcp//imaps///, 995/closed/tcp//pop3s///, 1723/closed/tcp//pptp///, 3306/open/tcp//mysql//MySQL 5.7.24/, 3389/closed/tcp//ms-wbt-server///, 5900/closed/tcp//vnc///, 8080/closed/tcp//http-proxy///
```

To a new file with fields separated by new lines:

```
$ sed -e 's/, /\n/g' nmap-scan.txt > nmap-new.txt

$ cat nmap-new.txt

Host: 45.310.302.11 (li982-11.members.ionic.com)    
Ports: 21/closed/tcp//ftp///
22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 5.3 (protocol 2.0)/
23/closed/tcp//telnet///
25/closed/tcp//smtp///
53/closed/tcp//domain///
80/open/tcp//http//Apache httpd/
110/closed/tcp//pop3///
111/closed/tcp//rpcbind///
135/filtered/tcp//msrpc///
139/filtered/tcp//netbios-ssn///
143/closed/tcp//imap///
443/open/tcp//ssl|http//Apache httpd/
445/filtered/tcp//microsoft-ds///
993/closed/tcp//imaps///
995/closed/tcp//pop3s///
1723/closed/tcp//pptp///
3306/open/tcp//mysql//MySQL 5.7.24/
3389/closed/tcp//ms-wbt-server///
5900/closed/tcp//vnc///
8080/closed/tcp//http-proxy///
```

Then grep the new file in simpler syntax:

```
$ grep -E '^80/|^443/' nmap-new.txt

80/open/tcp//http//Apache httpd/
443/open/tcp//ssl|http//Apache httpd/
```